# result from multiple UIPickers

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I work in a project that has two pickers and one button.
When the user chooses from the first and second pickers 
he click on the button .. and show the result in the textfield ..

for example: 
if he chooses from the first picker "Jed" and from the second picker "Ahmed"..
now if he clicks the button the result will be in the textfield shown "OK" ..

this is what I did so far .. I don't know why its crashing when I click on the button ..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var theResult: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cityTxt2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cityTxt: UITextField!


var city = ["Jed" , "Med" , "Ruh"]
var city2 = ["ahmed" , "mohammed" , "mustafa"]

let picker = UIPickerView()
let picker2 = UIPickerView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

    picker2.delegate = self
    picker2.dataSource = self

    cityTxt.inputView = picker
    cityTxt2.inputView = picker2


}

public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{

    return 1
}
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

    if (pickerView == self.picker) {
        return city.count
    }
    else if (pickerView == self.picker2) {
        return city2.count
    }
return city.count
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if (pickerView == self.picker) {
        return city[row]
    }
    else if (pickerView == self.picker2) {
        return city2[row]
    }

    return city[row]
    }



func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {



    if (pickerView == picker) {
        self.cityTxt.text = self.city[row]
    }
    else if (pickerView == picker2) {
        self.cityTxt2.text = self.city2[row]
    }



    self.view.endEditing(false)
}

@IBAction func getTheResult(_ sender: Any) {

    let R1 = cityTxt.text
    let R2 = cityTxt2.text

    if (R1 == "Jed") && (R2 == "ahmed"){

        theResult.text = "OK"

    }else{
        theResult.text = ""
    }

}



}
```

I think the problem is in the Button 
because when I click on it .. the program will crash ..

Comment: What's the complete error message? Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: this line : 
        if (R1 == "Jed") && (R2 == "ahmed"){

Comment: what error do you get on the console?

Comment: you have tp unwrap the String property try `guard let R1 = cityTxt.text, let  R2 = cityTxt2.text else { return }` make sure your button getTheResult it is properly connected right clicking the button (make sure there is only one connection)

Comment: thanks a lot Leo Dabus , it worked with me